# Get Updated or Deleted Record in Oracle Anonymous Block

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

I have a C# application that connects to a Oracle database. I generate PL\SQL statements dynamically and execute them using `CommandType=Text` (I don't use SPs).

My select statement is like this:

```
DECLARE
  -- <declaring>
BEGIN
  -- <some PL\SQL code>
  OPEN :refCursor FOR SELECT * FROM tablename
  -- <some PL\SQL code>
END;
```

In my C# code, refCorsor is a parameter of Type `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.RefCursor` which is added to parameters of my OracleCommand instance using output direction.

After ExecuteNonQuery call returns, I read my refCorsor parameter to get data from my select.

My problem is that when I want to get deleted records in Oracle using  `RETURNING BULK COLLECT INTO` clause.

As you know, in Oracle `RETURNING BULK COLLECT INTO` clause can be used to get columns of deleted records after a delete statement. This clause puts data in collections.

```
DECLARE
  TYPE RecordType IS RECORD("Id" INT,"Name" nvarchar2(50));
  TYPE IdsTableType IS TABLE OF RecordType;
  IdsName IdsTableType;
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM  "dbo"."AutoInt" WHERE "Name"='aaaa'
  returning "Id","Name"  BULK COLLECT INTO IdsName;
END;
```

Question is how can I read contents of `IdsName` from my C# code?

Comment: Basically your question is about `C#` and nothing to do with `Oracle PL/SQL`. But you explained it properly, hope someone with C# skills might help.

Comment: Not sure if this helps http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18593/Processing-with-C-and-Oracle-PL-SQL

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the set of records that are going to be deleted into the cursor before actually deleting them. The state of records will be maintained by Oracle when the cursor was opened.

```
DECLARE
  -- <declaring>
BEGIN
  -- <some PL\SQL code>
  OPEN :refCursor FOR SELECT * FROM "AutoInt" WHERE "Name"='aaaa';
  DELETE FROM  "AutoInt" WHERE "Name"='aaaa';
  -- <some PL\SQL code>
END;
```

Comment: So what is the use of 'RETURNING BULK COLLECT INTO' clause?

Comment: If you want to process further into the same Oracle code block the it is useful, but you want the data back to calling environment.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way is creating package with pipelined function -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package pkg_records as
    TYPE RecordType IS RECORD("Id" INT,"Name" nvarchar2(50));
    TYPE IdsTableType IS TABLE OF RecordType;
    function delete_auto_int RETURN IdsTableType PIPELINED;
END pkg_records;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE package body pkg_records as
    function delete_auto_int(name_ in varchar2) RETURN IdsTableType PIPELINED is
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    IdsName IdsTableType;
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM  "dbo"."AutoInt" WHERE "Name"= name_
      returning "Id","Name" BULK COLLECT INTO IdsName;
      commit;
      if IdsName.count > 0 then
          for i in IdsName.FIRST..IdsName.LAST loop
            pipe ROW(IdsName(i));
          end loop;
       end if;
    END;
END pkg_records;
/
```

then just use the simple select -

```
select * from table(pkg_records.delete_auto_int('aaaa'))
```